# Idiomatically return None if Option contains None or contains unwanted type

Tags: scala

I want to read the head of an possibly empty list and if that head contains a specific pattern I will return `Some()`, in all other cases I want to return None.

Here is my working code, but it's a bit ugly with the nested matches and re-wrapping the object in a Some() after unwrapping it.

```
 list.headOption match{
  case None => None
  case Some(csvString) => csvString.split(',') match {
    case Array(a, b, c) => Some(Array(a, b, c))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Is there a nicer, more idiomatic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `map` and `collect` you can do

```
list.headOption.map(_.split(',')).collect {
  case values @ Array(a, b, c) => values
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case you may use `.map`:

```
list.headOption.map(_.split(','))
```

And if you need to make sure the array has only 3 elements, you can use a combination of `.map` and `.filter`:

```
list.headOption.map(_.split(',')).filter(_.length == 3)
```

Or test a specific pattern:

```
list.headOption.map(_.split(',')).filter {
  case Array(a, b, c) => true
  case _ => false
}
```